# How can i add node.js project template or extension to VisualStudio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, npm

How can i add node.js project template or extension to VisualStudio? I have installed node.js tools from nuget but still i am not getting any javascript project in my VS2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't see the project types listed on the [official site](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Projects) you should try to install the tools via the msi package available on the site instead of NuGet.